# Router Hangs everytimes voltage fluctuate

Tags: adsl-router

I have D-link Router, every time voltage fluctuate, router hangs. Please provide some solution .

thanks

Comment: Purchase a UPS (Uninterruptible Power Supply) to plug the router into?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't detailed enough to answer. Voltage from where?
The mains power supply? If your mains power supply fluctuates often, this could indicate an issue in your electrical system, although a surge protector could prevent this issue.

If you mean that the power provided by your ISP fluctuates, this is normal, it's quite peculiar that the router would hang

I'm also slightly confused by "hang"
What does your router do when it "hangs". Hanging is generally just a lot of latency while the process queue frees up

When you've cleared up everything in the post, I'll be happy to offer further advice :)

Comment: Well let me explain there is a construction work running adjacent to my house where marble cutting machine is employed to cut d marbles. Every time machine runs produces fluctuation of electricity in my home causing my Router hang (stop working) even my PC got hanged. I usually plugged off (reboot) the router power supply for a few seconds. Thereafter my PC and Router start working normally. It happens repetitively and I could not able to work properly. Kindly advise some way out ?